# jquery(document).ready() fails to run in IE 7+

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, document-ready

This seems like really simple problem to me, but despite googling every possible search string, I cannot find an answer.

I'm using jquery 1.5.1 and trying to use the $(document).ready() function to bind several click events when the page loads. Eventually I narrowed down the problem to be this small:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('hello world');
});
```

In IE 6,7, and 8 I never see the hello world alert when I load the page. IE 9 works though, as does FF, Chrome, Safari etc.

A solution that sort of worked was to surround the alert in a 500ms JS timeout. This only seems to work sometimes but definitely not consistently enough.

The only possibility I can think of is that because this script happens to be loaded well inside the body tag of the page HTML, this might be messing up the ready() function. If that's the case, I don't know what the solution would be.

**UPDATE**

OK, after testing a smaller page I can get the document ready to work in IE (no alerts though, I guess that's a completely different problem).

Are there any quirks regarding IE in terms of where you can load the javascript files in the page?

Comment: Show us more of the page

Comment: is it definitely jQuery 1.5.1 that you are using? There is an issue with jQuery 1.5 with IE < 8 that I can go into further detail about if it is indeed 1.5 you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after messing with this I'm arriving at the conclusion that the IE browsers I'm using in a VM are at fault. The failure of the buttons and ajax calls to work correctly seems to be random and intermittent regardless of changes I make to the javascript. I think the document ready had been working all along and the browsers were failing in different ways. It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

What do you have in the `type=""` attribute? IE is very strict when it comes to that attribute. If you specify that attribute, it must contain `"text/javascript"` or else IE will ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other javascript files that could be conflicting with the jQuery $?

Conduct a test when the page loads,

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'js/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        setTimeout(checkjQuery, 0);
    }
    function checkjQuery() {
        if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
            setTimeout(checkjQuery, 0);
        } else {
            jQuery.noConflict();
        }
    };
```

Comment: I am using prototype side by side, but I have `var jq = jQuery.noConflict()` working. And have had no problems with that.

Comment: @scott: Other than your script periodically completely not working, you mean?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use `$(document).ready` inside the BODY of the page. Use it when your SCRIPT tag is in the HEAD of the page, or else remove it and don't add your SCRIPT tag until after all the necessary body elements are closed.

Comment: Even if I move it outside of the body tag it still doesn't work. This is part of an MVC application, so we have site header files and site footer files that get shared everywhere. It doesn't make sense to load this script everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem with IE7, it seems that I was using

```
<script type='application/javascript' language='javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() { ... })
</script>
```

Changing the first script tag to

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
```

Seems to make it work.  Hope this helps.